# Using list comprehensions, transform all vowels within a string to upper case?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Thanks for your help

Example byron = bYrOn

This is an old homework I'm looking over.

Comment: `"".join([letter.upper() if letter in "aeiouy" else letter for letter in string])`?

Comment: Alternative, without comprehensions: `string.translate({97:65, 101:69, 105:73, 111:79, 117:85, 121:89})`

Answer (score 0):

It is actually preety simple to turn all letters in a string to upper case!

just use the variable name and follow .upper() at the end e.g.

```
byron="byron"

byron=byron.upper()
```

however, because you want to give only certain letters the "uppercase" status, you'd want to first assign all vowels:

```
vowels = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
```

then use some python logic to do the rest:

```
for char in byron:
    if char in vowels:
        Word = Word.replace(char,(char.upper()))
print (Word)
```

if you want to be quick just copy the code below as it is the complete code used to do your task:

```
x="byron"
vowels = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
Word=x
for char in Word:
    if char in vowels:
        Word = Word.replace(char,(char.upper()))
print(Word)
```